# Can we write data from multiple Pubsub (source) to multiple GCS (sink) using a single Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I have 3 different Pubsubs (source) and 3 corresponding GCS buckets (sink) for them processing similar data. Currently my Java application provisions three Cloud Dataflow assets which write the data from the Pubsubs to the GCS buckets using windowed writes.

```
Current pipelines:
pubsub_topic_abc ---> dataflow_abc ---> gcs_bucket_abc

pubsub_topic_def ---> dataflow_def ---> gcs_bucket_def

pubsub_topic_ghi ---> dataflow_ghi ---> gcs_bucket_ghi
```

Is there a way I could make a pipeline to use a single Dataflow which could read data from multiple sources and write them to multiple corresponding sinks? Basically, data from `pubsub_topic_abc` should go to `gcs_bucket_abc` etc.

```
Desired pipeline:
pubsub_topic_abc ----                  ---> gcs_bucket_abc
                    |                 |
pubsub_topic_def -------> dataflow -------> gcs_bucket_def
                    |                 |
pubsub_topic_ghi ----                  ---> gcs_bucket_ghi
```

I found this [link](https://medium.com/@robinriclet/streaming-multiple-pubsub-subscriptions-to-gcs-with-fixed-windows-and-dynamic-naming-7f70cdd4584) which explains how a Dataflow can read from multiple Pubsubs but I am not sure how to implement the multiple sink write feature (dynamic output paths?). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. In your code, perform a loop like this

- For all sources (array of source Name for example)

  - Create the Pubsub reader on this source (you get a PCollection)
  - Apply the transformation on the PCollection
  - Create the sink dedicated to the Source for the transformed PCollection

You reuse the transformation but the source and the sink are specific. Your Dataflow graph will show you this

```
pubsub_topic_abc ---> transformation ---> gcs_bucket_abc

pubsub_topic_def ---> transformation ---> gcs_bucket_def

pubsub_topic_ghi ---> transformation ---> gcs_bucket_ghi
```

But all will run in the same dataflow job.